# Why can't I destroy php cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

In php, several months ago, I originally set a cookie like so:

```
<?php
setcookie('reituser', 'john', time()+3600*100000000000, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
?>
```

But now, I try to unset it like so

```
<?php
// this is the only line of code at http://mysite.com/test.php
setcookie('reituser', '', time()-10, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
?>
```

But no matter how many times I refresh my browser for `http://mysite.com/test.php`, the $_COOKIE  array is still populated with my reituser=>john .   How do I fix this problem?

For some reason, I can set new cookie variables and delete them via the methods above.  But it's jsut the reituser=>john that doesn't seem to work.  Is the word reituser a reserved word or something?

Comment: It's more likely that `SERVER_NAME` has changed in the meantime.

Comment: What browser are you using? I have often found that even browser upgrades can cause confusing scenarios, or you used a different host/domain in the cookie. In Firefox, I can inspect my cookies to see what the heck is going on when these sorts of things don't come through right, and coupled with Firebug listing the response headers, you can compare the two.

Comment: I am currently using Chrome 21.0 on Ubuntu .

Comment: @Jon you are correct, the domain has changed.  What should I do now?

Comment: @Jon - ok, this code fixed the problem `setcookie('reituser', '', time()-10, '/', '.mynewsitebecauseitchanged.com');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jon you are correct, the domain has changed. What should I do now? – John 2 days ago

@Jon - ok, this code fixed the problem setcookie('reituser', '', time()-10, '/', '.mynewsitebecauseitchanged.com'); – John 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
setcookie('reituser', '', time()-42000, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Also, you can see with Firefox + Firebug the cookie domain and other cookie values to see if you're giving the setcookie() function the proper parameters to unset it (namely, problematic on unsetting a cookie can be the path and domain parameters).